# How to validate ng-tags-input with promise?

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

Am trying to validate the tags added by calling a server-side api. Following is the code.

```
 <tags-input ng-model="user.trucks" 
             add-on-space="true" 
             on-tag-adding="checkTruck($tag)">
 </tags-input>
```

and in the controller I have written,

```
$scope.checkTruck = function(tag){
  var x = $q.defer();

  someService.checkTruck(tag).then(function(response){
      x.resolve(true);
  }, function(response){
      x.reject(false);
  });

  return x.promise; 
};
```

Though the documentation says that on-tag-adding can take a promise and validate the added tag, it's not working that way. Am I missing something ??

Comment: *"it's not working that way"* - what exactly happens?

Answer (score 1):

You do know you need to return values from your `resolve` and `reject` handlers !?

```
$scope.checkTruck = function(tag){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    someService.checkTruck(tag).then(function(response){
        return deferred.resolve(true);
    }, function(response){
        return deferred.reject(false);
    });

    return x.promise; 
};
```

We can then remove the [the explicit promise construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) you've done there and return a resolved or a rejected promise that will hold you boolean without the deferred object.

```
$scope.checkTruck = function(tag){
    return someService.checkTruck(tag).then(function(response){
        return $q.when(true);
    }, function(response){
        return $q.reject(false);
    });
};
```

That's how I do my validation

refer the [$q docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for more about `.when`.